# Index hierarchical or tree like data

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search. I need some help on how to index the following tree like data. I need to provide search on any node value and get the root value.

```
100                                   900
 |--1000--1001                         |
 |  |--1002                           800 
 |                                     |   
200--2001--2002--2003--2004-----------700 
 |    |      |--2020--2021           
 |    |--2010
 |         |--2011--2012
300--3001--3002
       |
       3010
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Graph from X-Pack to have full featured graph functionality
https://www.elastic.co/products/x-pack/graph

You also can store root and parent node reference in each node. You will have some redundancy in your data, but getting any node will give you information about root node. In extreme case you can keep full path to root node in any node.

Comment: Thanks. My original solution is to keep the full path to root in all nodes. I am looking for a better solution. Installing graph is not an option.

Comment: What are the use cases? Could you put examples of queries you would like to run on database.

Comment: Thanks. The requirements are changed now, one of the use case is when we search by a node value then return complete path to the root. I am not seeing any other way then saving complete path at each level.